# Is there a 3rd-party app that uses iPhone 6's barometer?

Tags: applications, iphone, temperature, apple-watch

I have an iPhone 6 and was wondering if there is any app that will simply display the current pressure using the barometer built into the phone?

Or an app, other then the built in HealthKit which tracks stairs climbed, that uses that barometric pressure for something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Barometer++](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/barometer++/id922220265?mt=8) (full disclosure: I worked on the app at [Friends of The Web](http://friendsoftheweb.com)) shows the raw pressure values from the iPhone 6 or 6 Plus's barometer sensor. It also shows sea-level adjusted pressure to compare to weather stations around the world (using your GPS altitude), and shows elevation changes based on the barometer.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few Apps in the App Store, including Barometer, Barometer+ and Barometer++. Take your pick. [This site](http://appcrawlr.com/ios-apps/best-apps-barometric-pressure) does the research for you.

Comment: Thanks! That is great. Do any of those apps use the built-in sensor?

Comment: @bassplayer7 Barometer++ uses the built-in barometer. It also shows sea level adjusted air pressure, or raw pressure from the sensor. (Full disclosure: I developed Barometer++). Here's a link to the app: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/barometer++/id922220265?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

Bar-o-meter is the best app at the moment. It reads the barometric sensor on the new iPhone 6/6+ and iPad Air 2. It also shows you altitude (from gps, from pressure and relative), displays up to 12 hours data in charts, has a widget and automatically fetches the value of pressure at sea level from the closest weather station. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bar-o-meter-altimeter-barometer/id930952204?mt=8
It's an easy and yet powerful utility.